# Hibernate Envers set username from Request

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have started using Hibernate Envers for my spring boot project and noticed that we should be saving user who is making changes to an entity .  We get the username as Request header in our Controller . How do we use the header value to save it to my custom Revision entity .
I went through posts which say to use Spring Security , but we are not receiving Authentication object from Zuul gateway . All authentication happens at Zuul gateway service , username is extracted and then passed as a header to backend micro-services .

Comment: You can access `RequestContextHolder` inside your custom `RevisionListener`. But, in any case, you should still probably be setting the authentication at some point inside your app, if you're planning on using Spring Security features

Comment: @crizzis I am using Spring security in my zuul gateway , how do I pass the Authentication context from zuul to my backend service.

Comment: What I meant was that once you are confident in your backend service that the user is indeed authenticated, you should call `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(...)` with appropriate user credentials and roles (in a custom request `Filter` for example), if you're planning to use Spring Security features like declarative authorization. Once that is done, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` will work just as well inside the `RevisionListener`, and it will be a more general solution, not tying the user credentials to the Web stack directly for audit purposes